# $inc not working mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a MongoDB data like this

```
{
 _id: "5aa8f087e1eee70004a99e1d"
 users: [{facebookId: "-1", unread: 0},{facebookId: "323232321", unread: 1}]
}
```

I want to increment users.unread where facebookId in not "-1"

I tried this query

```
chat.update({ "_id": { "$in": chatId }, "users.facebookId": { "$ne": "-1" } },{"$inc": { "users.$.unread": 1 } }, { multi: true, upsert: true }, function(err, data) {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log(data);
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From MongoDB [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/):

> If the query matches the array using a negation operator, such as $ne, $not, or $nin, then you cannot use the positional operator to update values from this array.
>
> However, if the negated portion of the query is inside of an $elemMatch expression, then you can use the positional operator to update this field

Below code should work if you want to increment first matching element:

```
db.chat.update({ "_id":"5aa8f087e1eee70004a99e1d", "users": { $elemMatch: { "facebookId": { "$ne": "-1" } }}},{"$inc": { "users.$.unread": 1 }})
```

Otherwise you can use array filters in MongoDB 3.6

```
db.col.update({ "_id":"5aa8f087e1eee70004a99e1d" }, { "$inc" : { "users.$[cond].unread" : 1 } }, { arrayFilters: [ { "cond.facebookId": { $ne: "-1" } } ]  })
```

Comment: i get this error callback.apply is not a function i tried the second one